# isset($_POST) too much times

Tags: php, isset

I'm making a simple menu application. I made a special class Dish, and I want to react on pushing buttons in my application. First of all you have to choose if you want to take dinner or drink and it works perfectly. Then you have to choose your cuisine (Polish Italian Mexican) and it works perfectly, but later you should be able to choose if you want a full meal or just dinner and for some reason it doesn't work. I work on the same rules like previous but it does not. Hopefully I'll get some answer instead of talking how bad my code is.

```php
<?php

    class Dish
    {
        private $Price;
        private $Name;

        public function setData($Price, $Name)
        {
            $this->Price = $Price;
            $this->Name = $Name;
        }

        function getPrice()
        {
            return $this->Price;
        }

        function getName()
        {
            return $this->Name;
        }

    }
    // It could be much faster by using database...

    $Polish_Dinner = new Dish;
    $Polish_Dinner->setData("3$", "Kapuśniak");
    $Polish_Desser = new Dish;
    $Polish_Desser->setData("3$", "Kapuśniak z cukrem");


    $Mexican_Dinner = new Dish;
    $Mexican_Dinner->setData("4$", "Fasola");
    $Mexican_Desser = new Dish;
    $Mexican_Desser->setData("4$", "Fasola z cukrem");


    $Italy_Dinner = new Dish;
    $Italy_Dinner->setData("5$", "Pizza");
    $Italy_Desser = new Dish;
    $Italy_Desser->setData("5$", "Pizza z cukrem");

?>
<div style="background-color: gray;">

    <?php
        $zamowienie[10] = new Dish;
        $i=0;
    ?>

    <form action ="index.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Dinner" name="Dinner" style="margin: 35px; display: inline;  ;width: 35%; height: 300px" />
                <input type="submit" value="Cash" name="Cash" style="display: inline;  width: 10%; height: 75px" />
                <input type="submit" value="Drink" name="Drink" style="margin: 35px   ; display: inline; width: 35%; height: 300px"/></br>
    </form>
        </br></br></br>
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST['Dinner']))
        {
            ?>
            <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkgreen;">
                <input type="submit" value="Mexican" name="Mexican" style="display: inline; width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                <input type="submit" value="Polish" name="Polish" style="display: inline;  width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                <input type="submit" value="Italy" name="Italy" style=" display: inline;   width: 10%; height: 100px"/></br>
            </form>
        <?php
        }
        elseif(isset($_POST['Drink'])) 
        {
        ?>
            <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkgreen;">
                <input type="submit" value="ice" name="ice" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                <input type="submit" value="lemon" name="lemon" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
            </form>
       <?php
        }
        switch(true)
        {
            case isset($_POST['Mexican']):

                ?>
                <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Mex_Lunch" name="Mex_Lunch" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Mex_Desser" name="Mex_Desser" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                </form>
                <?php
                echo "Mexican";
                    if(isset($_POST['Mex_Desser']))
                    {
                        echo "Mex_Des";
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Mexican_Desser;
                        $zamowienie[$i]->getName();
                        $i++;
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Mexican_Dinner;
                        $zamowienie[$i]->getName();
                        $i++;
                    }
                    elseif(isset($_POST['Mex_Lunch']))
                    {
                        echo "Mex_Din";
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Mexican_Dinner;
                        $i++;
                    }
                    echo $_POST['Mex_desser'];
                break;
            case isset($_POST['Polish']):
                 ?>
                <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
                    <input type="submit" value="Pol_Lunch" name="Pol_Lunch" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Pol_Desser" name="Pol_Desser" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                </form>
                <?php
                echo "POLISh";
                if(isset($_POST['Pol_Desser']))
                    {
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Desser;
                        $i++;
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
                        $i++;
                    }
                    elseif(isset($_POST['Pol_Lunch']))
                    {
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
                        $i++;
                    }
                break;
            case isset($_POST['Italy']):
                ?>
                <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
                    <input type="submit" value="It_Lunch" name="It_Lunch" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                    <input type="submit" value="It_Desser" name="It_Desser" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
                </form>
                <?php
                echo "ITALY";
                if(isset($_POST['It_Desser']))
                    {
                        echo "LUNCH + DESSER ITALY";
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Italy_Desser;
                        $i++;
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Italy_Dinner;
                        $i++;
                    }
                    elseif(isset($_POST['It_Lunch']))
                    {
                        echo "Lunch italy";
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Italy_Dinner;
                        $i++;
                    }
                break; 
        }
        ?>

</div>
```

**Moreover :** I'm really open to suggestion how it can be done better (I have to use `css` like this so please skip this comment).

Comment: *"Good evening guys"* - It's mid-day here ;-) but thanks (grazie). buona serata

Comment: I didnt sleep for 2 days so its evening for me all the time :P

Comment: It's best to code with a fresh mind. If coding's taking up all of that time, then you'll have a much harder time. Sleep is a coder's best friend ;-)

Comment: Tomorrow is my deadline and im gonna sleep like crazy for 3 days :P Its my last obstacle .... Its strange because it works perfect on previous values but it does not in this case...

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything, if this is an error-related issue.

Comment: Why you are using such a strange "switch" instead of another "if"?

Comment: Tried ,its not. When i add 
if(isset($_POST['Pol_Desser']))
                    {
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Desser;
                        $i++;
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
                        $i++;
                    }
                    elseif(isset($_POST['Pol_Lunch']))
                    {
                        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
                        $i++;
                    }
else
{
echo "It simple doesnt works!";
}

It prints me my message. I just dont know why cant he find this value in Post table...

Comment: It didnt work on if so i tried switch. It doesnt really matter :/

Comment: the main problem is: if the "Mexican"-Form is displayed to the user and he pushes the button, there is no $_POST['Mexican'] any more in that reqest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pseudo part of your code.

```
if ($dinner) {
  mexican or polish or italy
  also unsetting $dinner, so we won't get back here
}

if ($mexican) {
  Lunch or dessert
  also unsetting $mexican
  if ($lunch) {
    mexican lunch
  }
}
```

When you hit the following path:

```
Dinner->Mexican->Lunch
```

You want to enter `if($mexican){ if ($lunch){}}`, in other words: `if $mexican AND $lunch`.

**But** you unset $mexican when you press the lunch button. So `$mexican AND $lunch` won't be true. Your nesting is wrong.

---

I think my explanation is hard to understand. I didn't find the best words, but I hope you understand it.

Comment: I do understand it ( or i hope i do). But i dont understand why he doesnt go forward? I changed my code a bit:
http://wklej.org/id/1660958/

After choosing Dinner in $_Post should be 'Dinner' ,so he should pass to choosing cousine ( which he actually do) and goes forward with value (for examle 'Mexican') so he goes to next form and should go forward with 'Mex_Lunch' but he does not. Thats what i do not understand.

Comment: `$_POST` variables don't last. That array is filled, with what the last form passed it. And your Mexican Form only passes `Mex_Lunch` or `Mex_Dinner`. Not the needed `Mexican`. You could add a `<input type="hidden" name="Mexican" value="val" /> to fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Like i wrote in my comment above, the main problem was that if for example the Mexican-Form is displayed, there is no $_POST['Mexican'] any more when the form is submitted.

The following solution replaces your switch with a "if-else" and moved your "if-isset-mex_desser" which was inside the "if-isset-mexican" to a standalone "if-isset-mex_desser".

It is very hard to explain. Please look at the code and try to understand what happens on each form-post.

If you want the 3rd form to be shown after the last submit then you have to modificate it a little bit.

Hope it helps.

```
    <?php

    class Dish
    {
        private $Price;
        private $Name;

        public function setData($Price, $Name)
        {
            $this->Price = $Price;
            $this->Name = $Name;
        }

        function getPrice()
        {
            return $this->Price;
        }

        function getName()
        {
            return $this->Name;
        }

    }
    // It could be much faster by using database...

    $Polish_Dinner = new Dish;
    $Polish_Dinner->setData("3$", "Kapusniak");
    $Polish_Desser = new Dish;
    $Polish_Desser->setData("3$", "Kapusniak z cukrem");


    $Mexican_Dinner = new Dish;
    $Mexican_Dinner->setData("4$", "Fasola");
    $Mexican_Desser = new Dish;
    $Mexican_Desser->setData("4$", "Fasola z cukrem");


    $Italy_Dinner = new Dish;
    $Italy_Dinner->setData("5$", "Pizza");
    $Italy_Desser = new Dish;
    $Italy_Desser->setData("5$", "Pizza z cukrem");

    ?>
    <div style="background-color: gray;">

    <?php
        $zamowienie[10] = new Dish;
        $i=0;
    ?>

    <form action ="index.php" method="post">
                <input type="submit" value="Dinner" name="Dinner" style="margin: 35px; display: inline;  ;width: 35%; height: 300px" />
                <input type="submit" value="Cash" name="Cash" style="display: inline;  width: 10%; height: 75px" />
                <input type="submit" value="Drink" name="Drink" style="margin: 35px   ; display: inline; width: 35%; height: 300px"/></br>
    </form>
    </br></br></br>
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['Dinner']))
    {
        ?>
        <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkgreen;">
            <input type="submit" value="Mexican" name="Mexican" style="display: inline; width: 10%; height: 100px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Polish" name="Polish" style="display: inline;  width: 10%; height: 100px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Italy" name="Italy" style=" display: inline;   width: 10%; height: 100px"/></br>
        </form>
    <?php
    }
    elseif(isset($_POST['Drink'])) 
    {
    ?>
        <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkgreen;">
            <input type="submit" value="ice" name="ice" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
            <input type="submit" value="lemon" name="lemon" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
        </form>
    <?php
    }

    if(isset($_POST['Mexican'])) {
        ?>
        <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
            <input type="submit" value="Mex_Lunch" name="Mex_Lunch" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Mex_Desser" name="Mex_Desser" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
        </form>
        <?php
    } else if(isset($_POST['Polish'])) {
         ?>
        <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
            <input type="submit" value="Pol_Lunch" name="Pol_Lunch" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
            <input type="submit" value="Pol_Desser" name="Pol_Desser" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
        </form>
        <?php
    } else if(isset($_POST['Italy'])) {
        ?>
        <form action ="index.php" method="post" style="background-color: darkblue;">
            <input type="submit" value="It_Lunch" name="It_Lunch" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
            <input type="submit" value="It_Desser" name="It_Desser" style=" display: inline;width: 10%; height: 100px" />
        </form>
        <?php
    } else if(isset($_POST['Mex_Desser'])) {
        echo "Mex_Des";
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Mexican_Desser;
        $zamowienie[$i]->getName();
        $i++;
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Mexican_Dinner;
        $zamowienie[$i]->getName();
        $i++;
    } else if(isset($_POST['Mex_Lunch'])) {
        echo "Mex_Din";
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Mexican_Dinner;
        $i++;
    } else if(isset($_POST['Pol_Desser'])) {
        echo "LUNCH + DESSER POL";
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Desser;
        $i++;
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
        $i++;
    } else if(isset($_POST['Pol_Lunch'])) {
        echo "Lunch pol";
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Polish_Dinner;
        $i++;
    } else if(isset($_POST['It_Desser'])) {
        echo "LUNCH + DESSER ITALY";
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Italy_Desser;
        $i++;
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Italy_Dinner;
        $i++;
    } else if(isset($_POST['It_Lunch'])) {
        echo "Lunch italy";
        $zamowienie[$i]=$Italy_Dinner;
        $i++;
    }

    ?>

    </div>
```

Comment: Hmm sure ,when i will understand and fix problem i'll write long explanation ,np .

Comment: Hard to explain. a wrote a little bit. Hope you understand what i have done. There was a little bug in italy, i corrected it.

Comment: Wow ,now i do understand it. Thanks ,you are genious for me ;) Don't you think it's too "student" programming? I wanted to create menu,but this code is very long and uneffective. 

EDIT: Sorry ,it sounded bad, I dont say i think your solution is bad ,but I think my idea for this program is bad from the start. Dont you think so?

Comment: if it works and it is secure and it does what it should do then it is ok. Dont think too much about your coding style if you are a beginner. Time will bring you more experience to create better designed code. I personal would realize it with javascript and with one single POST at the end submitting all variables to the server. But you should learn step by step.